# Shared storage for GCP Windows autoscaling VM log files

Tags: windows, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I am new to GCP and am migrating over some Windows / dot net framework, IIS applications.

I would like to set up auto scaling groups. The autoscaling groups would be 10 VMs maximum.

All VMs write various logs which need to be accessible by another separate windows application, so I would rather these were not in buckets ideally. A network share would be preferred.

What is the recommended shared storage for windows autoscaling VM log files which, would allow up to 10 VMs to simultaneously write to it?

Comment: The logs **should** be written to Cloud Storage. Anything else will introduce complexity. Review multi-writer shared [persistent disks](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/sharing-disks-between-vms). However, setting that up for Windows systems is complicated and not realistic for managed instance groups.